# "<Model> is not defined" when creating Sequelize model associations

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying something that should be quite simple, and yet no scouring of the internet helped me with this specific problem.

Using Sequelize, I have modeled two simple database tables as a proof-of-concept for something here at work. They are the `Person` and `NaturalPerson` models below:

```
import { NaturalPerson } from './natural_person';
import Connection from './database/database.conn';
import { Model, DataTypes } from "sequelize";

export class Person extends Model {
    static isNaturalPerson(id) {
        return Person.findOne({
            include: [{
              model: NaturalPerson,
              required: true
            }],
            where: { id: id }
        });
    }
}

Person.init({
    'id': {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    'creation_date': {
        type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    sequelize: Connection,
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'person',
    modelName: 'Person'
});

Person.hasOne(NaturalPerson, { foreignKey: 'person_id' });

export default Person;
```

```
import { Person } from "./person";
import Connection from './database/database.conn';
import { Model, DataTypes } from "sequelize";

export class NaturalPerson extends Model { }

NaturalPerson.init({
    'id': {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    'rg': {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: true
    },
    'cpf': {
        type: DataTypes.CHAR(11),
        allowNull: true
    },
    'name': {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    'birth_date': {
        type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
        allowNull: true
    },
    'person_id': {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: 'person',
            key: 'id'
        }
    }
}, {
    sequelize: Connection,
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: "natural_person"
});

NaturalPerson.belongsTo(Person, { foreignKey: 'person_id', targetKey: 'id' });
```

For some unknown reason, if I comment out the line `NaturalPerson.belongsTo(Person, { foreignKey: 'person_id', targetKey: 'id' });` everything works fine and dandy, but uncommenting it returns me

```
ReferenceError: Person is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (<source code path>\natural_person.js:45:31)
```

I have no more idea of what the problem may be. Even though I know it's a simple undefined object, I can't understand why it is undefined if the imports are correct. Any idea will be very welcome. =(

Comment: I actually see it may be a circular reference problem, but as I have produced this example following strictly what the Sequelize documentation describes as being my use case, I'm still stuck...

Comment: I have the same issues, can you resolve this?

Comment: I also have this issue, has anyone found a solution?